# Printing Google Maps - screen size affecting print size

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps-api-3, printing

**Background**

I'm writing a Google Maps web app (API v3) and I want the user to be able to print what they see on screen.

The map div is 100% wide and 100% high with various bits and bobs over-layed including the markers and application controls etc.

I'm using a @print set of css rules to remove the bits I don't want to print and all that is working perfectly.

**The problem**

The problem I am having is that the map is far too wide for the page (and actually a bit too high as well). (with size set to 'Shrink To Fit' in the print set up).

I'm using Firefox mainly for the development, but testing in Chrome and IE and am seeing the same thing.

If I have a full screen browser window on my 1920x1080 monitor the pint preview and print output is only about 50% of what is shown on screen.

If I reduce the print size in the Print Preview dialog to 50% things look about right.

If I reduce my browser window to about half its horizontal size (and by just a little bit vertically) then things look just about right.

So, the problem seems to be browser window size dependent - ie the browser window is showing more map than can be printed.

Essentially what I'm trying to achieve is having the all of the displayed map print as tall and as wide as possible dependent on the users printer settings - a true 'Shrink To Fit' if you like. But I can't seem to get anywhere with this.

**'Solutions' I've tried**

One solution that's been suggested in other threads is to generate a fixed-size popup window of a suitable size for the print - this is what I previously did in my API v2 application (I'm re-writing from scratch for v3) - but this isn't working either. With the popup I only get the smaller 'viewport' displayed - ie roughly the same portion of the map as would be printed (I guess this confirms that my window size is about right!).

I'm generating the popup with the following:

```
var content = window.document.getElementById("map-canvas"); // get you map details
var logoBox = "<div class='logoBox' id='logoBox' style='width:300px;    height:65px; border-radius:4px; background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.75);    box-shadow:5px 5px 2px rgba(50,50,50,0.5);  float:left; z-index:10; position:absolute;  top:10px;   left:10px; padding:5px;'><img src='myLogo_300x65.png' id='myLogo'></div>";
var printWindow = window.open("","printWindow", "Width=640, Height=620,location=no,menu bar=no,resizable=no,scrollbars=no,status=no,titlebar=no,toolbar=no"); // open a new window
printWindow.document.write(content.innerHTML); // write the map into the new window
printWindow.document.write(logoBox); 
printWindow.print(); // print the new window
```

There's another oddity with this as well - on mobile the pop-up map displays with the same markers set displayed as the main calling page, but on FireFox on the desktop it opens up with just one of my markers.

**Ideas**

I'm thinking the solution might be something to do with one or more of the following:

- the print css forcing a proper scale to fit, or

  placing a printable element in the bottom right of the map in case the browser is seeing the map tiles as not important enough to scale to, or

  needing to do a getBounds on the bigger map and setting those on the smaller map to zoom the map appropriately.

Re the final point here, I've tried to get my head around this but am struggling with calling a fitBounds() in the new pop-up window from the main window.

So far I've got:

```
var displayedMapBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds;
displayedMapBounds = map.getBounds(); // map is the Google Maps instance on the main page
// printWindow.map.fitBounds(displayedMapBounds); // This doesn't work for semi-obvious reasons
printWindow.document.map.fitBounds(displayedMapBounds); // This doesn't work for semi-obvious reasons
```

This is inserted in the above code after the dowcument.write statements.

I'm sure those semi-obvious reasons are actually obvious to most, but is there a way to reference the map object and manipulate it from the main window like this?

Any pointers gratefully received as this is the show-stopper for the relaunch of the site.

Comment: Interestingly, placing a print only element bottom right shows in the bottom right of the printout or print preview regardless of the print zoom setting. Quite what this implies I don't know, but the map tiles seem to be being treated as less important somehow. Still doesn't fix the problem though.